# Оптимизация PhpShop

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть интернет-магазин на движке `PhpShop 3.1`. В нем около 2500 товаров. Кушает он более 200 МБ и хостер за это пинает.
Проблема в том, что он со старта не выбирает нужные товары из БД, а берет ВСЕ и помещает их в массив, к которому обращается в дальнейшем.
Вот график использования памяти:

[image: график использования памяти]

Нужно это оптимизировать.
Вот нашел статейку на хабре: [Оптимизация PHPShop](http://habrahabr.ru/post/62470/)
Хочу сделать тоже самое, но не понимаю как они добились, чтоб данные попадали в массив только при обращении?
Сделать это нужно "незаметно" для остальных скриптов, т.е. они и дальше будут обращаться к массиву как раньше, чтоб не ковырять весь движок.

Подскажите что имеется ввиду в статье и как это сделать.

UPD:

PhpInfo: [info](http://fedotka.ru/info.php) - древний php 4.4.9 ((
Вот вся статистика за последний год: [stat](http://forstudents.by/stat/)

Comment: Идеальный вариант - смените движок. Глупо платить за то, что приходится допиливать.

Ну а что касается статьи, то, ИМХО, они изменили способ формирования массива, превратив его в объект, который запрашивает данные из БД для нужного индекса только при обращении к этому индексу. Подробности реализации подсказать не смогу - давненько не работал с phpshop. Но полагаю, что изучив возможности интерфейса ArrayAccess (http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) Вы и сами сможете создать аналогичный "оптимизационный" костыль.

Comment: @Равнодушный, хм. Точно они в БД лазят при каждом обращении. Буду дальше разбираться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По графику видно, что потребление памяти стало расти резко и внезапно, что указывает или на достигнутый придел БД по размеру или на чье-то хулиганье из конкурентов или множественные потери изображений и "зацыкливание" отсутствующих изображений на неверной 404 ошибки через индекс, который каждый раз дергается и создается "автоминидосс". Для начала посмотреть логи на предмет многочисленного одинакового IP, далее проанализировать размер БД через PhpMyAdmin, очистить большие таблицы временные (таблица логов, таблица поиска). Выполнить команду оптимизации БД. Скачать с оф-сайта свежую версию и взять файл .htaccess и посмотреть как работает с ним. В панели управления выключить сообщение о новых заказах/сообщениях. В PHPShop давно нет больших массивов, обращается к БД и выбирает данные только по заданному каталогу в пределах лимита пагинатора. Кол-во потребляемой памяти самим движком можно посмотреть в исходном коде в самом конце, пример БД 32 запроса ~ 0.0818 sec, 4570.91 Kb. Что бы набрать 200MB нужна хорошая периодическая долбешка индекса, что может быть только в случаях, что я описал. Еще одним боком является несанкционированное вмешательство SEO мастеров, например Demis ставит свой index перехватчик с "регуляркой" и потребление памяти возрастает в разы.

UPD
1 24170 6.82% 16361 5.18% 154405 4.19% 49 0.51% 94.79.54.150 
2 18925 5.34% 18380 5.82% 0 0.00% 0 0.00% 212.193.234.171

Если это не ваши IP 94.79.54.150, 212.193.234.171 то их нужно заблокировать в .htaccess. Еще настораживает  в логе запись перехода на главную страницу с редиректа. Покажите свой .htaccess

Comment: @Dennion, спасибо за столь широкий ответ. На DDos проверю.  
Вот, что в БД:  
- ведение журнала в  phpshop_jurnal (6200 записей)
- ведение журнала rss в  phpshop_rssgraber_jurnal (900 строк)
- ведение журанла в  phpshop_search_jurnal (42000 строк)
- фотки в phpshop_foto (4700 записей)
- товаров в phpshop_products 2400  
  
Все журналы выключу.    
Действительно пофиксили выборку всех продуктов. Сейчас выбираются ВСЕ из одного каталога, хоть и выводится их на страницу только 10.

Comment: У меня на локалке память подскакивает на 10-20 МБ при выполнении запроса. Самая ресурсоемкая операция - вывод всех товаров категории.  
Еще подозрительно, что товаров 2400 в БД, хотя в реальности их не так много на сайте.  
Кол-во потребляемой памяти так и не понял где смотреть( В исходнике страницы в конце есть: "StNF 74 ~ 0.3386" - оно?

Comment: 1. Забилась таблица журнала поиска за 4 года, нужно очистить ее выполнить
TRUNCATE phpshop_search_jurnal;
TRUNCATE phpshop_jurnal;

2. выполнить OPTIMIZE TABLE ....

Надо посмотреть по логам, бывают добрые души начинают душить страницы
/search/
/shop/CID_XXX_ALL.html

Для них нужно сразу добавить исключение на IP в .htaccess, пример так
deny from 157.55.36.36
deny from 157.55.32.109

StNF 74 ~ 0.3386 - это 74 запроса к БД и выполнение за 0.3 секунды. В принципе это терпимо.

Comment: Еще нужно посмотреть на вариант подмеса на ftp вируса, особенно в корне файлы типа bd.php или image.php со свежей датой изменения (судя по графику - март 2013). 

Кроме сайта магазина другие сайты на этом аккаунте не стоят, там джумлы или форумы?

Comment: Для логирования можно создать функцию записи в файлик. Память выделяется примерно так 

// Расход памяти
if (function_exists('memory_get_usage')) {
    $mem = memory_get_usage();
    $_MEM = round($mem / 1024, 2) . " Kb,";
}else
    $_MEM = null;

дальше $_MEM писать в memory.txt
но, тот что вы показали файлик обычно дают хостинги nic.ru,beget.ru, в них показана нагрузка связки Апача+php. Из этого графика выделить отдельно перегрузку php нельзя. А апач можно и дерганием статичного html прибить. Логи нужно смотреть. Если есть статистика по логам, то обратить внимание на самые популярные файлы.

Comment: @Dennion, стоит еще в корне Wordpress просто как папка. Но вроде ничего подозрительного.  
Память с Вашим кодом действительно выводит ~700 КБ )  
В первую очередь БД почищу и сделаю оптимизацию таблиц. Может это поможет. И буду со статистикой разбираться.  
Спасибо Вам огромное) Очень помогли.

Comment: @Dennion, извиняюсь, что уже надоел наверно. Просто на хостинге почему-то не работает memory_get_usage (( Как еще можно?

Comment: php какая версия? ОС какая?
Вот так еще http://php.ru/manual/function.memory-get-peak-usage.html
Но если одна прикрыта, то вторая обычно так же.
В распечатке phpinfo() в поле запрещенных функций ее случайно нет?

Answer (score 0):

[@Dennion](/users/12942/dennion), обновил главный пост.